# Stuck on old Ruby version (macOS)

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I keep trying to get ruby on my system from v 2.3.7 to v 2.7.1 but no matter what command I enter (update, install, rbenv global etc) it stays with the old version. I think it's an old installation that doesn't get overwritten when I install a new version, but whenever I try to run something with the "ruby" command it only uses the 2.3.7 install.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. This was after was trying to uninstall everything I could to do a full reinstall, but I can't even figure out how to uninstall it. I then tried to upgrade the ruby version that the system was telling me was there, but brew couldn't find it.

$ ruby -v

ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

$ brew upgrade ruby

Updating Homebrew...

Error: ruby not installed

Comment: Have you considered using [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)? Are you already using it? If you are, you don't use `brew` to update Ruby, you use `rbenv` directly.

Comment: `which ruby` will tell you where your Ruby comes from.

Comment: Or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) which makes it easy to have multiple versions of Ruby installed.

Comment: Or [chruby](https://stevemarshall.com/journal/why-i-use-chruby/)

Comment: @jazaniac : You mentioned that you have used `rbenv`, but I don't see any _rbenv_  command in your question. I don't see what you gain when using `rbenv` and `brew` together. You should think of your goal: Having a **single** Ruby of a certain version on your system, or do you want to easily switch between versions. I personally would not touch the version which comes with MacOS, but add other vesions in addition.

Answer (score 1):

[`brew upgrade ruby`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#upgrade-options-formulacask) upgrades the ruby installed ***by Homebrew***. "Error: ruby not installed" says you don't have Ruby installed by Homebrew. Homebrew will not upgrade the Ruby that comes with MacOS.

Instead, [`brew install ruby`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#install-formula). This will leave your MacOS Ruby alone and install its own.

Comment: Solution ended up being to use rvm, but you suggested that too so I'm gonna check this answer. Thanks for the further explanation. Will my native version still be fucked up after using rvm or will it fix it completely?

Comment: @jazaniac `rvm` will not touch the Ruby that comes with MacOS; `rvm` installs in your home directory. Your MacOS provided Ruby isn't fucked up, unless there's something you're not telling us, it's just old. If you want to develop in Ruby use the rvm versions. Treat the MacOS Ruby like a component of MacOS and leave it alone. This goes for Python, Perl, PHP, and any other languages that come with the OS.

Comment: @jazaniac Perhaps understanding [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) will help.

Comment: I've legit tried all these commands and the ruby version is still stuck on 2.3.7. Same goes for all guides I've found on editing my path. rvm is still the only thing that works.